# Converting a long string into number accurately in ios

Tags: iphone, ios

Let my string is 77777788888
after converting to float its coming as 77777788928.
But I want the accurate number

I have already tried with [str floatValue],[str doubleValue] and [str longlongValue]

Comment: This might not be the case, but if you're using this to save for example a telephone number or something of the likes (something that doesn't need mathematical manipulations), you might be better of using a NSString instead.

Answer (score 0):

To float

```
float myFloat = [myString floatValue];
```

To Double

```
double myDouble = [myString doubleValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"%.0f", [@"77777788888" floatValue]);
NSLog(@"%.0f", [@"77777788888" doubleValue]);
NSLog(@"%lld", [@"77777788888" longLongValue]);
```

Produces the output

> 77777788928
>   77777788888
>   77777788888

So if you are not getting good results, something else is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the problem is that your double is going out of range, check this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851831/what-is-the-range-of-a-double-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

int is a 32 bit/4 byte value.

I am surprised are cannot comprehend (as of now), why you are getting that.

For now, you can use the following and this will work —

```
NSString *string = @"77777788888";
NSLog(@"%lld", [string longLongValue]);
```

I'll surely post a reply when I understand the issue.

Regards